# ZeroMQを使った、パブサブシステムの構築

Tags: python

只今、『入門 Python3』を読みながら、
JupyterLabを使ってPythonを学んでいます。
OSはwindows10です。

『P.351 11.2.2.2 ZeroMQ』より。

以下のコードは、ZeroMQにより、パブサブシステムのサブスクライバを書いたものです。
このサブスクライバは、メインクーンとペルシアンの猫をトピックに入れ、いま、パブリッシャからの配信を待とうとしています。

```
import zmq

# zmqソケットの定義をする。
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 6789
ctx = zmq.Context()
sub = ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)
sub.connect('tcp://%s:%s' % (host, port))

# トピックを定義する。
topics = ['maine coon', 'persian']

# トピックの含んだメッセージだけを受信するように設定する。
for topic in topics :
    sub.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, topic.encode('utf-8')

# 受信したbytes列をデコードして表示する。
while True :
    cat_bytes, hat_bytes = sub.recv_multipart()
    cat = cat_bytes.decode('utf-8')
    hat = hat_bytes.decode('utf-8')
    print('Subscrebe : $s wears a %s' % (cat, hat))
```

問題は、これを起動したときに、

```
    while True :
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

と表示されることです。
なにか初歩的なミスをしていますでしょうか？

Comment: Akira ejiri様、回答ありがとうございます。
他にも謎の空白が差し込まれておりました。
恥ずかしい気持ちがいたします。
今度からはコードはエディタで書こうと思います。

Comment: 私も参考書の写経でPythonを勉強しました。IDEのコード補完もお世話になりました。`print('Subscrebe : $s wears a %s' % (cat, hat))`はチェックツールのPyLintが見つけてくれました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> sub.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, topic.encode('utf-8')

は`()`の対応がとれていません。最後に`)`が必要です。
『入門 Python3』ではそうなっています。

```py
sub.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, topic.encode('utf-8'))
```

> print('Subscrebe : $s wears a %s' % (cat, hat))

の`$s`も`%s`の誤りですね。

```
print('Subscrebe : %s wears a %s' % (cat, hat))
```